# Sockets in Rust

Tags: sockets, rust, rust-obsolete

Are there any socket or net libraries for Rust? The `net` page in the standard library documentation seems to only include address-related functions.

Comment: There is an issue for this https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/1828

Comment: Are the answers in this question still current ?

Comment: @static_rtti, Probably no.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [std::net](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/net/) exists for working with sockets.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann, this does provide an answer. Since the question was asked, sockets support was added to `std::net` module in the standard library.

Answer (score 7):

There is also a [bsd socket library](https://github.com/jdm/rust-socket) in cargo, which you can install with:

```
$ cargo install socket
```

I haven't tried it out yet though. Or if you want to use zeromq, you could use my [bindings](https://github.com/erickt/rust-zmq). You'll need to be using rust's HEAD version though, as it's using code that was added after the rust 0.1 release. Feel free to ping me on irc.mozilla.org's #rust channel if you need any help. I'm erickt there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [UnixListener](https://tokio-rs.github.io/tokio-uds/tokio_uds/struct.UnixListener.html) from the tokio crate.

> This crate provides bindings between mio_uds, the mio crate for Unix Domain sockets, and futures. The APIs and bindings in this crate are very similar to the TCP and UDP bindings in the futures-mio crate. This crate is also an empty crate on Windows, as Unix Domain Sockets are Unix-specific.